# requested 'with a working example' to call parameters from config.js to a feature in Karate-DSL

Tags: karate

**My requirement:**

*Say, I have set the dbusername and dbpassword in karate-config.js, **how can I call dbusername in a feature file and assign it to a variable?***

I see some way as follows

```
# if the js file evaluates to a function, it can be re-used later using the 'call' keyword
* def someFunction = read('classpath:some-reusable-code.js')
```

If I have declared some-reusable-code.js as follows,

```
function fn() {
  var env = karate.env; // get system property 'karate.env'
  var myBaseUrl = 'https://reqres.in/api/users/2'
  var dbusername = 'myDBUserName'
  var dbpassword = 'myDBPassword'

  karate.log('karate.env system property was:', env);
  if (!env) {
    env = 'dev';
  }
  var config = {
    env: env,
    myVarName: 'someValue'
    myUrl: 'http://reqres.in/users'
  }
  if (env == 'dev') {
    // customize
    // e.g. config.foo = 'bar';
  } else if (env == 'e2e') {
    // customize
  }
  return config;
}
```

But when I read the  entire, 'some-reusable-code.js', how could I assign 'dbusername' or 'myNarName' or 'myUrl' to **myVar** as a local variable in myuseful.feature?

Will it be possible to give **a working example please**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#configuration

You are missing the part where you return `dbusername` as part of the `config` returned when the function exits. Then you don't need to do anything extra in your feature, `dbusername` will be available as a (global) variable. Try this hard coded `karate-config.js` and understand it:

```
function fn() {
  def config = {};
  config.dbusername = 'myDBUserName';
  config.dbpassword = 'myDBPassword';
  return config;
}
```

now in your feature:

```
* print 'dbusername:', dbusername
```

You can find a **working example** here: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-demo